# Is it possible for the host to follow a symlink into a docker container?

Tags: docker

**Problem**

I want to create a docker container and bind mount a local folder, e.g.:

```
docker -it run --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd),dst=/data busybox sh
```

I then want to:

1. Create a new symlink in `/data` linked to a file outside of the mount (e.g. `/data/abinary -> /usr/local/bin/abinary`)
2. Exit the container
3. Access the newly created symlink from the host (even though it resolves to a file outside the mount)

Is this possible using docker?

**Context**

The context is I have a docker container with a python environment. I want to be able to access the python binary from my host, even if the file I'm accessing is a symlink to a file outside the mount.

Or in other words, I want the following two commands to do the same thing when run from the host:

```
./python
```

```
docker exec -it mycontainer /data/python
```

Answer (score 2):

A Docker container has an isolated filesystem.  A container cannot access files on the host (without a bind mount) and the host cannot access files in the container.  In particular, with the setup you describe, the host cannot directly invoke the Python installation in the container.

A symbolic link stores the name of a file as a directory entry.  In the case of a Docker bind-mount, how that is interpreted depends on whether you're looking at the host or container filesystem.

You can demonstrate this by creating a host directory containing a symlink, then bind-mounting it into containers running different distributions and seeing what it does.

```shellsession
$ mkdir x
$ ln -s /usr/bin/more x

$ ./x/more --version # on a MacOS host
less 581.2 (POSIX regular expressions)

$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD/x:/x" ubuntu /x/more --version
more from util-linux 2.37.2

$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD/x:/x" busybox /x/more --version
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/x/more": stat /x/more: no such file or directory: unknown.

$ docker run --rm busybox /bin/more --version
/bin/more: unrecognized option `--version'
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2022-03-10 23:58:34 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

So here we've created a symlink to `/usr/bin/more`.  Running it on the host returns the host version of `more`; in an Ubuntu container, the `util-linux` version of it; and in a BusyBox container, an error (because the tool is actually in `/bin`).  In no case does the symbolic link cross from the container filesystem to the host, or *vice versa*.